# Count files in directory on a time

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I'm using macOSx, and i want to count all files in directory then print the result sorted by last Modified time.
like this:

```
1241 2014-12-08 07:00:00 +0700
4123 2014-12-08 08:00:00 +0700
2241 2014-12-08 09:00:00 +0700
```

etc..
i tried with ruby, but i can only puts count of files with this:

```
dir = 'original'
puts Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')].count { |file| File.file?(file) }
```

or puts all file and sorts it by time like this:

```
Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')].sort_by{ |f| File.mtime(f) }
```

So how can i do this? may be with bash script, or ruby...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the request. do you have subdirectories or need sort all files in subdirectories as well? if not, I use this command

```
ls -lctr
```

#### explanation

```
 -l      (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format.  (See below.)  If the output is to a terminal, a total sum
         for all the file sizes is output on a line before the long listing.
 -c      Use time when file status was last changed for sorting (-t) or long printing (-l).
 -t      Sort by time modified (most recently modified first) before sorting the operands by lexicographical order.
 -r      Reverse the order of the sort to get reverse lexicographical order or the oldest entries first (or largest files
         last, if combined with sort by size
```

If you need count the files, use this:

```
find . -type f |wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = []
count = 0
Dir.glob("/path/**/*").each { |file| 
  if  File.file?(file)
    count+=1
    arr << File.mtime(file)
  end
}
puts count.to_s + " " + arr.sort.last.to_s
#=> 2241 2014-12-08 09:00:00 +0700
```

This will not consider the sub directory files though

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly

```
Dir["Other/**"].sort_by{ |f| File.mtime(f) }.each do |item|
  if File.directory? item  
    print "#{Dir[File.join(item, '**', '*')].count} #{File.mtime(item)}\n"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [tap](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) to count files, like this:

```
require 'fileutils'
dir = '.'
p Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')]
    .tap{|el| p el.length }
    .sort_by{ |f| File.mtime(f) }
```

Which prints count and sorted array of files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bash script to go into folder and execute command from there.

```
#!/bin/bash
curdir=$(pwd)
for f in $curdir/<parent folder name>/*
  do
     [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f && wc -l
  done;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my ruby code:

```
require "Date"
dir = 'original'

for date in 1..7 do
  for hour in 0..23 do
    d = DateTime.new(2014, 1, 1, hour, 0, 0)
    d1 = DateTime.new(2014, 1, 1, hour+1, 0, 0)
    time = d.strftime("%H:%M")
    time1 = d1.strftime("%H:%M")

    puts ("Files on time 12/0#{date}/2014 #{time} (from #{time} -- #{time1}) :")
    puts Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')].count {|file|
      if ("12/0#{date}/2014 #{time}" < File.mtime(file).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M')) && (File.mtime(file).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M') < "12/0#{date}/2014 #{time1}")
        File.file?(file)
      end
    }
  end
  puts ("Files on time 12/0#{date}/2014 23:00 (from 23:00 -- 00:00 next day) :")
  puts Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')].count {|file|
    if ("12/0#{date}/2014 23:00" < File.mtime(file).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M')) && (File.mtime(file).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M') < "12/0#{date+1}/2014 #{time1}")
      File.file?(file)
    end
  }
end
```